# Placing generated tikz pictures using nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Suppose I have a \newcommand drawing a tikz picture. How do I place multiple of these pictures using nodes? Specifically, I have a command

\row that draws a row of colored squares the way I want. Now I want to place some of these rows below each other.

```
% x position, y position, colour, number. 
\newcommand{\coloredSquare}[4] {
    \draw[fill=#3] (#1, #2) +(-.5,-.5) rectangle ++(.5,.5);
    \node at (#1, #2) {#4};
}

% Argument one is the row number, argument two is the size of the cache 
% line in words.
\newcommand{\row}[2] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \b in {1, ..., #2} {
            \coloredSquare{#2 * 0 + \b - 1}{0}{green}
                {\pgfmathparse{#1 * #2 * 4 + #2 * 0 + \b - 1}\pgfmathresult}
            \coloredSquare{#2 * 1 + \b - 1}{0}{yellow}
                {\pgfmathparse{#1 * #2 * 4 + #2 * 1 + \b - 1}\pgfmathresult}
            \coloredSquare{#2 * 2 + \b - 1}{0}{red}
                {\pgfmathparse{#1 * #2 * 4 + #2 * 2 + \b - 1}\pgfmathresult}
            \coloredSquare{#2 * 3 + \b - 1}{0}{blue}
                {\pgfmathparse{#1 * #2 * 4 + #2 * 3 + \b - 1}\pgfmathresult}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

I tried something like

```
% Second argument is the size of the cache line in words,
% the product of the arguments is the total memory size. 
\newcommand{\cacheLayout}[2] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \a in {1, ..., #1} {
            \node at (\a - 1, 0) \row{\a - 1}{#2}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

but it does not compiled. Putting everything in one command gets super weird results.

The goal is to create something like this, but with the numbers being
the row-major index.
[image]

Comment: Have a look at `\pic`in the pfg manual.

Comment: @MS-SPO [this](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) one? It's not in there.

Comment: This one ([`pgfmanual.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)) or an unofficial html version tikz.dev.

Comment: Since `\row` creates a `tikzpicture`, calling it inside of another `tikzpicture` produces undesirable results. Could you describe the results you want? Perhaps a hand-drawn picture? I'm certain there's an easier way.

Comment: The second command `\cacheLayout` is just to place a `\row` over the other, then why not include both commands in one? This way you don't need to nest tikzpictures which is never recommended.

Comment: @SandyG I edited my post to show a picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[image]

In this case, I've used two `foreach` loops. The first one jumps along the list of `row-major index`, and this value is used to compute the first number on corresponding row.

Except the number of rows, all other values (number of columns and color width) are fixed, but it's not too difficult to parametrize them.

About different colors in each row, I've used [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367353/1952) to [How to make TikZ style conditional on comparing two numeric style parameters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367334/1952)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    byte/.style={draw, fill=#1, minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt},
    myfill/.is choice,
    myfill/1/.style={byte=green!70},
    myfill/2/.style={byte=yellow!70},
    myfill/3/.style={byte=red!70},
    myfill/4/.style={byte=blue!70}]
\foreach \i [count=\row (init from 0)] in {0,20,3,10,5}
    \foreach \col in {0,1,...,15}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myfill{ifthenelse(\col<4,1,{ifthenelse(\col<8,2,{ifthenelse(\col<12,3,4)})})}
        \node[myfill=\myfill] at (\col, -\row) {\the\numexpr16*\i+\col\relax};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```